# Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range despite the range being created from data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing here in this Google script. I keep getting the error

> *Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 15.*

but it doesn't make sense to me.

Here's the bit of code in question:

```
var range = ReleaseSchedule.getRange(1,1,output_data_sheet.length,output_data_sheet[0].length);
range.setValues(output_data_sheet);
```

ReleaseSchedule is a new sheet in the active spreadsheet output_data_sheet is a 2 dimensional array. I have similar code working earlier in the script, but for some reason this one is throwing that exception and I can't figure out why. Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I proposed 2 modified scripts for your situation. But I'm not sure about your whole script. So if my guess for your situation was not correct, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the whole script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Are you sure that the the output_data_sheet data has the same number of columns, even the first row? It is best to use a debugger `Logger.log(output_data_sheet.length, output_data_sheet[0].length)`to check if those values are in line with what you expected.

Comment: Can you provide the script related to the retrieval of `output_data_sheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that the reason of this error of `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 15.` might be as follows.

- `output_data_sheet` is 2 dimensional array.
- The array length of the 1st index of `output_data_sheet` is `15`
- The empty array (the array length is `0`) is included in the index except for 1st index.

When above `output_data_sheet` is used for `setValues()`, such error might occur. In order to remove this issue, how about the following modifications? Here, I would like to propose 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the empty elements are removed from `output_data_sheet`.

From:

```
var range = ReleaseSchedule.getRange(1,1,output_data_sheet.length,output_data_sheet[0].length);
range.setValues(output_data_sheet);
```

To:

```
output_data_sheet = output_data_sheet.filter(String);  // <--- Added
var range = ReleaseSchedule.getRange(1,1,output_data_sheet.length,output_data_sheet[0].length);
range.setValues(output_data_sheet);
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the empty elements and the element smaller than the length of 15 add the elements for keeping the length of 15 for each index in `output_data_sheet`.

From:

```
var range = ReleaseSchedule.getRange(1,1,output_data_sheet.length,output_data_sheet[0].length);
range.setValues(output_data_sheet);
```

To:

```
output_data_sheet = output_data_sheet.map(r => r.length == 15 ? r : r.concat(Array(15 - r.length).fill("")));  // <--- Added
var range = ReleaseSchedule.getRange(1,1,output_data_sheet.length,output_data_sheet[0].length);
range.setValues(output_data_sheet);
```

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

In the next column to the last column of data you need, there might be some content that is not visible but it's there and that's what the script picks up.
I resolved this by adding the following line of code :-

ws.getRange("J1:J").clearContent();

Where J is the first empty column. I required data from column A to I.

PS :- The above code snippet is the part of function that calls all sheets within the folder and fetches the data from those sheets into one master sheet.